# BeginCollectionItem can not bind partial values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, collections

I´m doing [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) tutorial, but I can´t bind values of my ViewModel to my Create View

Model:

```
 public class WebPages
{
    [Key]
    public int WebPagesId { get; set; }

    public String DomainName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DomainStart { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DomainExp { get; set; }
    public String DomainEmails { get; set; }
    public String DomainUsers { get; set; }
    public String DomainPasswords { get; set; }

}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class WebPagesViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String DomainName { get; set; }

    public class Domain
    {
        public String DomainEmails { get; set; }
        public String DomainUsers { get; set; }
        public String DomainPasswords { get; set; } 
    }
    public List<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}
}
```

Create GetController

```
 public ActionResult Create(WebPages model)

    {

     var ejemdata =  new List<WebPagesViewModel.Domain>
        {
            new WebPagesViewModel.Domain
            {
                DomainEmails = "email@gmail.com",
                DomainUsers = "Testuser",
                DomainPasswords = "testpassword"
            }
        };

        var vm = new WebPagesViewModel
        {
            Clients = new SelectList(db.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "ClientsName"),
          Domains = ejemdata
        };


        return View(vm);
    }
```

Create View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Domains)
        {

            { Html.RenderPartial("_WebPagesPartial", item);} 

        }
```

Partial:

```
 @using xxx.Models.ViewModels
 @model WebPagesViewModel.Domain
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem

 <h2>Partial View</h2>

 <div>
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Domains"))
{

        Html.EditorFor(x => x.DomainPasswords);
        Html.EditorFor(x => x.DomainUsers);
        Html.EditorFor(x => x.DomainEmails);
}
```

I use breakpoint debug, and controller gets values from my `ejemdata` and it pass to my create view into `foreach`

[Receiving data in View photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htZf6.png)

So when the page loads it only loads label from partial but no display anything that is in BeginCollectionItem method and I get this on HTML

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Domains.index" autocomplete="off" value="28f4e8e7-cde3-44fe-a739-b4c8acb15ec2">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use of

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x.DomainPasswords);
```

just calls the method but does not output its result. You need to change it to

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DomainPasswords)
```

(and ditto for the other 2 HtmlHelpers)